# Match Regex in MySQL for repeated word with condition exclude the parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm having a query problem. I use mysql as DB. I want to use a REGEX to match the result I expected and The Table is

```
table A

----------------------------------
|   ID  | Description            |
----------------------------------
|   1   |  new 2 new 2 new 2 new |
|   2   |   new 21 new 2 new     |
|   3   |   new 2th 2 (2/2)      |
|   4   |   2new 2new (2/2)      |
|   5   |   new2 new 2new        |
```

The Result I expected 
 - numeric 2 can only show twice 
 - character after/before 2 must be varchar (except after whitespace) 
 - special condition : any numeric with pattern "(numeric/numeric)" like ID=3 and ID=4 is acceptable

---

```
|   ID  | Description           |
---------------------------------
|   3   |   new 2th 2 (2/2)      |
|   4   |   2new 2new (2/2)      |
|   5   |   new2 new 2new        |
```

the query I've tried so far

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a227b/2

Comment: sorry.. wrong typing

Comment: In your second expectation what do you mean except for whitespace

Comment: -It doesn't show the result in ID=2 because after 2 there is 1 (character after/before 2 must be varchar ) 
-It will show the result in ID=3 because after/before 2 there just whitespace (except after/before whitespace)

Comment: id=4 doesn't belong according to your rules.

Comment: What you mean by varchar is alphabets/letters, right? varchar is a data type and not a character type and varchar can contain *any* character, literally. And can there be more than one special condition of (numeric/numeric)? Like `2new 2new (2/2) (2/2)` or the numbers changes positions as in `(2/2) 2new 2new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this regex:

```
^([^2]|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*([[:<:]]|[a-z])2([[:>:]]|[a-z])([^2]|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])+([[:<:]]|[a-z])2([[:>:]]|[a-z])([^2]|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*$
```

It's a bit long, but it allows some more flexibility in that those strings are considered 'valid' as well:

```
(2/2) 2new 2new
2new (2/2) 2new (2/2)
```

---

**In code**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A
WHERE 
    description REGEXP '^(([^2]+|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*2([[:>:]]|[a-z])){2}([^2]+|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*$'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a1b0b/4)

**Regex breakdown**

The regex actually uses many repeating parts, so that's why it's a bit long:

```
^                                        # Beginning of string

(                                        # Open repeat group
   ([^2]+|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*  # Any characters. See #1
  2                                      # 2
  ([[:>:]]|[a-z])                        # Word boundary or alphabet/letter. See #2
){2}                                     # Close repeat group and repeat 2 times

([^2]+|[[:<:]][0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:>:]])*     # Any characters. See #1

$
```

**Detailed breakdown**

- **#1**

  ```
  (           # Open group

    [^2]+     # Any characters except 2

  |           # OR

    [[:<:]]   # Open word boundary
    [0-9]+    # Any numbers
    /         # Forward slash
    [0-9]+    # Any numbers
    [[:>:]]   # Close word boundary

  )*          # Close group and repeat any number of times
  ```
- **#2**

  ```
  (           # Open group
    [[:>:]]   # Word boundary
  |           # Or
    [a-z]     # Letter/alphabet
  )           # Close group
  ```

A word boundary matches the beginning and end of words. The definition of a word here is a series of alphabet, numbers and underscore characters.

`[[:<:]]` is an opening word boundary and thus matches at the start of a word.

`[[:>:]]` is an opening word boundary and thus matches at the end of a word.

Their use here ensures that `2` (and the numeric/numeric parts) are not surrounded by other numbers (hence makes `21` fail for example) or count a `2` if you have for example `21/4` as one which counts towards the two `2`s in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do this with one regular expression, but I find it easier to use three:

```
select *
from a
where description regexp '[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9]+' and
      (description not regexp '[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+' or
       description regexp '[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+/[0-9]+'
      );
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize the goal was only for `2` and not any digit.  This fits your rules but not your results (4 doesn't belong):

```
select *
from a
where description regexp '[a-zA-Z ]+[2]+[a-zA-Z ]+[2]+' and
      (description not regexp '[2]+[^0-9]+[2]+[^0-9]+[2]+' or
       description regexp '[2]+[^0-9]+[2]+[^0-9]+2/2'
      );
```