# failed matching regex in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm having a query problem. I use MySQL as DB. I want to use a `REGEX` to match the result I expected and the Table is:

```
table A

-----------------------------------------------
|   ID  | Description                         |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1   |  29th Marine Regiment/1st Bn (1/29) |
|   2   |   new 21 new 2 new                  |
|   3   |   new 2th 2 (2/2)                   |
|   4   |   2new 2new (2/2)                   |
|   5   |   new2 new 2new                     |
```

The result I need to get :

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   ID  | Description                         |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1   |  29th Marine Regiment/1st Bn (1/29) |
```

I have the correct result for regex

```
^(29[^0-9]+)[^0-9]+1[^0-9]+\([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*\)\s*$
```

in http://www.regexr.com/ but I don't get the result in MySQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd4b/2

Does anyone know how this happen?

Comment: Trimming your regex to what I *think* you want it to be I got this working one: `'^29[^0-9]+1[^0-9]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*\\)\\s*$'` Note the `\\‍`s.

Comment: Any update on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25615003/1578604)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer.)

You need to escape backslashes!  E.g. `\(` → `\\(`.

And there are some other issues:

- The group in the beginning is not used anywhere, so it can be removed.
- `[^0-9]+[^0-9]+` (once the group has been removed) is rather redundant.  It can be shortened to `[^0-9]{2,}`, but in this case it looks like `[^0-9]+` will suffice.
- The fiddle version had some strange `{}`s that had to be removed.

The result is thus:

```
'^29[^0-9]+1[^0-9]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*\\)\\s*$'
```